# Prisma.io How to filter where ENUM field has ANY value

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, nexus-prisma

I have a handful of ENUM type fields and I would like to do a `where` filter where the field value is ANYTHING. Basically, I want is `where`
{fieldName_is_set: true}`

Does something like this exist? The only way I can think to do this is:
`where: { fieldNam_in: [all the enum values]}`

I'm not a fan of this approach because it requires me to maintain that list of `all the enum values`.

Comment: Is the field in question nullable?

Comment: I believe so, considering most of the ENUM type properties do have null values. I am able to save without setting a value. Or clear it after a value is already set.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is nullable, then you can use the following filter to match any enum value:

```
where: { NOT: [{ fieldNam: null }]}
```

If the field is non-null, then simply omitting the filter altogether will match any value.